# Autodesk APS - Can't get all Hubs / folder files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to list folder files with a two leg authentication, on a BIM360 project ([aps documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/)).
With 3 leg token, no issues.
With 2 leg token, no issues on some HUBS but on others API returns forbidden.

The Hub that raises the forbidden, is not listed with [GetHubs](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/) both with 2leg and 3leg token, despite the fact that files under that folder can be listed and retrieved with 3 leg authentication.

Is this raised by a HUB configuration? How to set the configuration to allow for 2leg token?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 2 legged authentication, you need to add "User-Id" in your headers.

The user ID can be retreived from if you look at the documentation on https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/profile/v1/reference/profile/oidcuserinfo/

It should be the sub.

Comment: "x-user-id"? The user must be admin to the HUB?

Comment: The admin always has access to the hub. But if not admin, the user must be associated with one project in the hub